# How to create a full response by combining two REST API JSON responses from async function block [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, json, async-await

new to JS and `async/await` methodology. I have two REST APIs that return JSON, I need to call these two APIs separately and then combine both of the responses and create a final JSON file.
I am able to get response from both the APIs but due to async/await architecture my final variable is not getting updated with the latest values.
In the final function under `console.log` I can only see my one key which I hard coded in the beginning, rest keys from both the APIs are not showing up neither getting written in the file.
Any help would be nice. Thanks

code:

```
var http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const values = async (key,callback)=>{
    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: xxxx,
        path: `/${key}/to/api1`,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            let object = JSON.parse(chunk);
            let  xx = object['type']; //returns array of JSON
            let b ='';
            let c ='';
            let d ='';
            let e='';
            for(let key in xx){
                if(xx[key]['error'] == 'bug'){
                    b = xx[key]['hist'][0]['value'];
                }
                else if(xx[key]['error'] == 'ct'){
                    c = xx[key]['hist'][0]['value'];
                }
                else if(xx[key]['error'] == 'st'){
                    d = xx[key]['hist'][0]['value'];
                }
                else if(xx[key]['error'] == 'vt'){
                    e = xx[key]['hist'][0]['value'];
                }               
            }

            let yy = {
                co: c,
                bo: b,
                eo: e,
                do: d
            };
            callback(yy); // Gives back the JSON value correctly to the caller function in final..
        }); 
    }).end();
}

const values2 = async (callback)=>{

    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: xxxx,
        path: '/path/to/api2',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {

            /* Here Same code as earlier.... 
            *
            it forms a JSON by filtering reponse from the API using if/else logic
            */

            let yy ={
                cm: c,
                bm: b,
                em: e,
                dm: d
            };
                callback(yy); // Gives back the JSON value correctly to the caller function in final.. 
        }); 
    }).end();
}



const final = async (mykey)=>{

    // want this variable to conatin the content of both the JSON reponses and finally write this variable to a file
    let finalJson ={
        key:mykey, // first key of finalJson. 
    };  


    // Calling to get the values from first reponse in JSON format to put in the finalJson variable
    await values(mykey,(chunk)=>{
        finalJson['values1'] = chunk;   // Response from fisrt API will be under second key 'values1' in the finalJson (cross checked using console.log, its coming correctly)
    });

    await values2((chunk)=>{
        var d = new Date();
        finalJson['values2'] = chunk; // Response from second API will be under third key 'values2' in the finalJson
        finalJson['time'] = d.toJSON().slice(0,19).replace('T',':');  // fourth and last key of finalJson 'time'

    });

    console.log(finalJson); // finalJson print only the first key named, 'key' 

    // Only writes the first key of finalJson rest it skips
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(finalJson);
    fs.writeFile('./file.json', jsonString, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error writing file', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Successfully wrote file');
        }
    });

}

final('mykey');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await values(mykey,(chunk)=>{
        finalJson['values1'] = chunk;   // Response from fisrt API will be under second key 'values1' in the finalJson (cross checked using console.log, its coming correctly)
    });\
```

is misusing the async/await syntax. You should make your async functions return whatever you`d like them to return, then store the value inside a variable, obviously, if you need it later. Like, for example

```
const asyncFn = async () => {
         ......

         return x;
}

const valueYouNeed = await asyncFn();
```

In the code you showed us, you are mainly using `http` in your "async" functions in a callback-style fashion, which makes going for async/await syntax useless, and in this case broken too. If you are currently experimenting with async/await and http requests, I suggest you try the `axios` or `request-promise-native` npm modules, which I personally think would fit your case best.